# Better way to plot a matrix where each value is function of 2 parameters

Tags: matlab, data-visualization

Suggestions to visualize plots 2 variable function.

I have Accuracy values as a function of hidden layers and regularization parameters.

Data is a n x p matrix. Rows are different values hidden layers. Columns are different values for reg param.

```
 0.95 0.91 0.86 0.85 .. 0.9
 0.95 0.96 0.85 0.81 .. 0.7
 ..........................
 ..........................
 0.95 0.96 0.85 0.81 .. 0.7
```

It would be great to have some direction how to visualize/plot this data so that it tells which combination of hidden layer and reg param is best.

Comment: What do you mean "which combination of hidden layer and reg param is best"? Do you mean "which entry of the matrix is largest", or is it something more elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about good ol' `imagesc`?

```
A = [ 0.95 0.91 0.86 0.85 0.9
      0.95 0.96 0.85 0.81 0.7
      0.95 0.96 0.85 0.81 0.7 ];
imagesc(A)
colorbar
axis image
```

From the image you can easily read the entry/entries with maximum value.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Though I had thought about imagesc, was thinking there is some other way to show a better representation.

Comment: @dissw.geek9 Well, maybe someone will come up with an alternative. Thanks for accepting my answer, but you should consider un-accepting it if you are not satisfied with `imagesc`. That way your question will appear as "unanswered" in the general list